# Validity Of Template Pattern Invoking Factory method which creates an instance of the Abstract Class

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

Let's assume the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
         * Assume following input:
         * input = "'https://test.com/file1.csv'"
         * 
         * Where the link https://test.com/file1.csv content:
         * "word1, '/Users/test/file2'"
         * 
         * where the file /Users/test/file2 content:
         * "'https://test.com/file3.csv', word4"
         * 
         * Where the link https://test.com/file3.csv content:
         * "word2, word3"
         * 
         * Expected output:
         * output = ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]  
         */

        List<String> output = TransformFactory.get("'https://test.com/file1.csv'").transfrom();
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}

class LinkContentTransformer extends BaseTransformer {
    private final String link;

    public LinkContentTransformer(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContent() {
        String linkContent = "dummy"; //assume http.get(link).body
        return linkContent;
    }
}

class FileContentTransformer extends BaseTransformer {
    private final String fileLocation;

    public FileContentTransformer(String fileLocation) {
        this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContent() {
        String fileContent = "dummy"; //assume fileReader.readFile(fileContent)
        return fileContent;
    }
}

abstract class BaseTransformer {
    public List<String> transfrom() {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String word : getContent().split(",")) {
            word = word.trim();
            if (word.startsWith("'") && word.endsWith("'")) {
                output.addAll(TransformFactory.get(word).transfrom());
            } else {
                output.add(word);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    protected abstract String getContent();
}

class TransformFactory {
    public static BaseTransformer get(String word) {
        if (word.startsWith("'https")) {
            return new LinkContentTransformer(word);
        } else if (word.startsWith("'/")) {
            return new FileContentTransformer(word);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    }
}
```

Is this a valid usage of template pattern? Is there anything wrong with it?
The concern I have is **BaseTransformer** calls **TransformFactory** that returns one of it's childs (**LinkContentTransformer** or **FileContentTransformer**) to invoke transform method recursively, is this a valid concern? appreciate an answer with good explanation.

Comment: Looks like a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle to me. Downloading content and transforming it are two different jobs for two different classes.